# Using if else statement around div tag with variable in a cshtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am currently having difficulty successfulling adding the following code to my View, which is a .cshtml file.

I have an if and else statement that render different panels depending on a condition.

My code is as follows:

```
foreach (var item in groupItem)
{
   @if (item.NextDue < DateTime.Today)
   {
     <div class="panel panel-danger" id="panel_@i">
   }
     else
   {
     <div class="panel panel-info" id="panel_@i">
   }
}
```

I have tried lots of combinations of @{ around the code, but I think that the issue is the ids also have an @ symbol.  If I comment out the code within the foreach loop, the code executes fine.  However, adding the code into the foreach loop results in an error of "closing } of the foreach loop is not found"

Any help on being able to execute this code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `True` in the `if` block (have you declared a boolean variable named `True`?) And what is `i` - is this in a loop?

Comment: True is the result of a Boolean that I have declared.  The actual code is @if(overdue == True), but thought this was irrelevant for the main question.  Yes this code is in a loop, foreach (item) and i increases after every execution of this code.

Comment: It would just need to be `@if(overdue) {..}` :) But post your real code including the loop. No point posting code which cant be tested and wont even compile

Comment: Your already inside a razor block (the `foreach` loop) so you don't need the `@if (..` - it should be just `if(..`. Can you post the exact error message you getting

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you do it...

```
    @{
    int[] x = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    string alertClass = "";
}
@foreach (var y in x)
{
    if (y % 2 != 0)
    {
        alertClass = "panel-info";
    }
    else
    {
        alertClass = "panel-danger";
    }
    <div id="panel_@y" class="panel @alertClass">Some Text_@y</div>
}
```

Comment: The use of the @i is because the panels are appearing for a large data set, and the panels need to relate to unique ids.  My goal is to render either red or blue panels based on a separate condition.  Therefore, in this case, the unique id's would be reused as this code relies in a foreach loop.

Comment: so...are you asking how to get unique ids out of a foreach loop? Post the loop...if your looping over a data set then I would use the primary key of the record for the panel id.

Comment: Currently, this snippet of code is not working in my View, i.e. the if closing { and else statement are not being read as C#.  I want to know how I can make them read as C#.  The error is "the block is missing a closing "}" character".  How can I get rid of this error and execute this code?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your page. Check the nesting of your code blocks. That error says it all...your missing a } some where or you have an extra { somewhere. Post the view.

Comment: I know, but if I comment out just the snippet of code I posted, the View renders perfectly and there is no error.

Comment: I changed my answer.. I didn't understand what you where asking.

Comment: Thank you! You're solution is perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a starting `<div>` tag but no ending tag, so razor doesn't expect the ending bracket there. You can use the `<text>` tag to specify what the content is when razor has trouble parsing it:

```
@foreach (var item in groupItem)
{
   if (item.NextDue < DateTime.Today)
   {
     <text><div class="panel panel-danger" id="panel_@i"></text>
   }
     else
   {
     <text><div class="panel panel-info" id="panel_@i"></text>
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however, the issue is more with the recognition of the else statement and the closing parenthesis of the if statement.  Therefore, this does not fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to change the panel color base on a condition, you can do this:

```
<div class="panel @(item.NextDue < DateTime.Today ? "panel-danger" : "panel-info")">
    ...
</div>
```

If the condition is true, if will use panel-danger. otherwise it will use panel-info.